# Problems with python + json vs. curl

Tags: python, json, google-maps, curl, google-geolocation

so when I run the python code the server (google) give me a different response than when I run curl command. Can someone tell me where I'm wrong please?

code:

```
import urllib2, simplejson

def MapsWIFI(card):
    req = urllib2.Request("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AI...")
    jWifi = """
{
 "wifiAccessPoints": [
  {
   "macAddress": "64:D1:A3:0A:11:65",
   "channel": 6,
  },
  ... #some AP here
 ]
}
    """
    print jWifi
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
    jWifiReport = urllib2.urlopen(req,simplejson.dumps(jWifi)).read()
    print jWifiReport
    APdetected = str(len(wifiCell))
    mapsDict = simplejson.loads(jWifiReport)
    location = str(mapsDict.get("location",{}))[1:-1]
    accuracy = "Accuracy: "+str(mapsDict.get("accuracy",{}))[1:-1]
    mapMe = "|---"+location.split(",")[0]+"\n|---"+location.split(",")[1][1:]+"\n|---$
    return mapMe

MapsWIFI("wlp8s0")
```

And the command is:

```
curl -d @file2.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AI..."
```

where file2.json contains exactly jWifi in that format.
The problem is that, as said, the location returned by the code is different from the location returned by curl. I don't get error code so I thing that the syntax is correct.

Comment: Out of interest, why use the `simplejson` library? Python 2.7 comes with the `json` module, which is *the exact same project*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But this is a part of a project that aim to be as portable as possible, so this should work with others versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is *already* a JSON encoded string, you don't want to encode it twice.

Pass it in *without* encoding it again:

```
jWifiReport = urllib2.urlopen(req, jWifi).read()
```

You only need to encode if you have a Python data structure (a dictionary in this case).